# Cross-compiling coreutils

Tags: arm, cross-platform, gnu-coreutils

I have problems trying to cross-compile the GNU coreutils (*git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/coreutils.git*) for ARM.

Following other Q&As in the StackExchange network, I ended up with the following procedure:

Setup:

```
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/coreutils.git
cd coreutils/ && ./bootstrap
[...]
```

Cross-compilation:

```
export CC=/path/to/toolchain/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
export CXX=/path/to/toolchain/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```

Compile:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf
[...]
make
  GEN      .version
[...]
  GEN      lib/wchar.h
  GEN      lib/wctype.h
  GEN      src/coreutils.h
  GEN      src/dircolors.h
make src/make-prime-list
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/data/sources/coreutils'
  CC       src/make-prime-list.o
  CCLD     src/make-prime-list
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/data/sources/coreutils'
  GEN      src/primes.h
/bin/bash: src/make-prime-list: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
Makefile:14603: recipe for target 'src/primes.h' failed
make: *** [src/primes.h] Error 126
```

Y U no compile?
I see that it tries to run this `make-prime-list` on my x64 machine, hence the format error. But it is supposed to compile with the toolchain anyway...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To cross-compile, you should only specify the `--host` option to `./configure`, you mustn’t specify your cross-compiler as `CC` and `CXX`. The `configure` script should do the right thing, using the host compiler for host binaries such as `make-prime-list`, and the cross-compiler for target binaries...

However it appears that it doesn’t, so `src/primes.h` can’t be generated. That file doesn’t appear to be arch-specific though, and `make clean` doesn’t remove it, so the following works for me:

```
./configure && make
```

to build `make-prime-list` for the build architecture, and use that to generate `src/primes.h`, followed by

```
make clean && ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf && make
```

to cross-compile the target binaries.

Comment: Great, thanks Stephen. That solved the issue with `make-prime-list`, however I couldn't get it to compile anyway for linker errors "Using '<command>' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking". http://dpaste.com/3CFANWY

Comment: The error you’re getting is “multiple definition of `__mktime_internal`”; the library warning you quote above is just a warning. The `mktime` error looks like a problem with your toolchain; I’m using the Debian cross-compilers in Debian 9 (`apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`).